# My python code doesn't run and don't show me any error

Tags: python

```
> print('¡Hi, welcome!')

> while(True):
   > option = input('''\n¿What you want do? ¡Select an option!
   > (A) Greet
   > (B) Add two numbers
   > (C) Exit''')
   > if option == 'A':
      >  print('\n The developer sends his regards \n')
   > elif option == 'B':
       > n_1 = float(input('\n Enter a first number \n'))
       > n_2 = float(input('\n Enter a second number \n'))
       > print('\n The result of the sum is {}'.format(n_1+n_2))
   > elif option == 'C':
       > print('\n A pleasure. Greetings')
       > break
   > else:
       > print('\n There is an error. Choose again')
```

Here's the code, i try runit in other archive and run perfectly, i don't know why i can't do it run in the actual.

Comment: For starters `opción` and `opcion` are not the same variables.

Comment: if you are new to programming, consider using an IDE to help detect any potential syntax errors

Comment: Take a look at [flake8](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/) it integrates with many editors and can highlight trivial errors!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. The code runs for me, but errors when I select `C`. Please provide a [mre]. You might need to check how you're running the script.

Comment: "The Kernel is busy", that's the explication i can find in other post at SO. Thanks to all! I interrupt the Kernel and problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
elif opcion == C:
```

doesn't seem to have the ó, and C is not defined.